# Django could not import myproject.settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-settings

I am far from being a django pro but I am stuck trying to put something on the server and I have never done that before. I have been searching the internet and been passed around between around 10 tech support guys for 2 days. I had to install python and django on the server, which appears to work. They had me set up a virtualenv which I also know nothing about but it's there. Here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./index.fcgi", line 18, in <module>
    runfastcgi(method='threaded', daemonize='false')
  File "/home/empirede/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py", line 182, in runfastcgi
    WSGIServer(get_internal_wsgi_application(), **wsgi_opts).run()
  File "/home/empirede/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 51, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    app_path = getattr(settings, 'WSGI_APPLICATION')
  File "/home/empirede/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/empirede/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/empirede/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)

ImportError: Could not import settings 's5test.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named empireDesignlanding.settings
```

I have looked at the many other similar questions, and maybe I just don't know what is going on, but I tried to replicate them and had no luck.

Side: They had me change the name of the auto generated sub directory of the project folder (the one that has the same name) I'm fairly sure that will change the code in some spots but I'm not sure if that effects this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `manage.py` file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "path.to.your.settings.file")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: That was alright, I figured out something was wrong with the index.fcgi file and after that Python was missing a file. Thank you though.